# Multiple versions of the same package using npmjs

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json, install.packages

Anyone knows a trick to install multiple versions of the same package through `npmjs` ? I know it's not possible to use the same package-name in `package.json` but it gives you an idea of what I try to achieve:

```js
"dependencies": {
  "mypackage": "user/mypackage#v1.0",
  "mypackage": "user/mypackage#v2.0"
}
```

At the end, I want to A/B test my package with different versions. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Based on npm discussion, this won't be implemented any time soon.

Some reference:

- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5499
- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2943